# update array then update stage

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I'm trying to write some code for a simple product scroller.
I have an array of product items and when the user clicks the next button I want to remove the item at the last index of the array add add it to the start index and then update the stage with the results.

Answer (score 1):

```
//create a new Array
var item:Array = [];

//add the last element of your Array
item[0] = myArray.pop();

//merge both arrays with the last element as the first element
myArray = item.concat(myArray );

//update the stage with the new value of myArray
```